# Url rewriting to add extra word

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I want to make url like

http://website.com/controller/action/parama-name/extra-word/param-value

i.e. I want to add word between get parameter name and get parameter value using URL rewriting. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you doing this in a programming language?

Comment: yes, i am doing in a programming language

Comment: Can you add what code you have and add it in the tag?